# What are the solutions to $X$ for $X^{T} A X = A$? Knowing that, what are the solutions to Y for $Y= (I−X)(I+X)^{-1}$ (with $\det(I+X) \neq 0$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

All matrices are square matrices of real numbers. The goal is to use these properties to show that $$AY+Y^{T}A= 0$$

What do the equations in the title reveal about the properties of $A$, $X$, and $Y$? Can $X$ only be the identity matrix?

Thanks!

---

loup blanc's edit: This question is about showing that the solutions of $X^TAX=A$ are in isomorphism with the solutions of $AY+Y^TA=0$. Recent research (2011) has made it possible to know the dimension of the solutions of the second equation, then the dimension of the solutions of the first one.

Comment: If $A$ is the identity matrix, then $X$ can be any orthogonal matrix.  An analogous result applies whenever $A$ is symmetric and positive definite

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: For those who are interested, one can find the dimension of the algebraic set of the solutions of $X^TAX=0$ when $A$ is symmetric invertible or (more difficult) when $A$ is generic. cf. my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105787/find-x-in-mathbbm-n-such-that-ax-xta-0/3341169#3341169

Answer (score 3):

In view of the expression for your $Y$, here is a pertinent result:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $A$ is symmetric and nonsingular over a field of characteristic $\ne2$. Then every solution to the equation $X^TAX=A$ with $\det(I+X)\ne0$ is in the form of $X=(A+K)^{-1}(A-K)$ for some skew-symmetric matrix $K$ such that $A+K$ is nonsingular. Such a matrix $X$ is called a *cogredient automorph* or *congruent automorph* of $A$.

For a proof of the above theorem, see Sam Perlis, *Theory of Matrices*, pp.104-105.

In the special case where $A=I$ over $\mathbb R$, the equation $X^TAX=A$ reduces to $X^TX=I$ and hence $X$ is a real orthogonal matrix, and the expression $X=(A+K)^{-1}(A-K)$ in the theorem above becomes $X=(I+K)^{-1}(I-K)$, which is the familiar [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Matrix_map).

Some more general results for a nonsingular but perhaps non-symmetric $A$ can be found in sec. 37 (pp.65-68), chapter V of Mac Duffee's detailed survey *The Theory of Matrices*.

Comment: Well done, I didn't know this generalization. When $A$ is symmetric $>0$, it's easy to see that it works, because $X=A^{-1/2}QA^{1/2}$ where $Q\in O(n)$. Then, using the  above formula giving $X$, we obtain $A^{1/2}XA^{-1/2}=(I+A^{-1/2}KA^{-1/2})^{-1}(I-A^{-1/2}KA^{-1/2})=(I+H)^{-1}(I-H)$ where $H$ is skew symmetric. Moreover, $\{X,X^TAX=A\}$ is an algebraic set of dimension $n(n-1)/2$ (independent on $A$).

Comment: In fact, the OP's problem is equivalent to show the formula in Perlis' book. According to the  @Omnomnomnom 's post, $AY+Y^TA=0$ that is $(I+X)^{-1}(I-X)=A^{-1}K$ where $K$ is skew symmetric, that is, $X=(A+K)^{-1}(A-K)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without characterizing the solutions to your equations, we can say the following:

Suppose that $X$ is a solution to $X^TAX = A$, and that $Y = (I - X)(I + X)^{-1}$.  Because $\det(I+X) \neq 0$, it suffices to show that
$$
(I + X)^T[AY + Y^TA](I + X) = 0.
$$
With that in mind, we note that we can expand
$$
\begin{align*}
(I + X)^T[AY + Y^TA]&(I + X) =
(I+X)^TA(I-X) + (I-X)^TA(I + X) \\
&= A - AX + X^TA - X^TAX + A - X^TA + AX - X^TAX\\
&= A - AX + X^TA - A + A - X^TA + AX - A 
= 0.
\end{align*}
$$
The desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at  $(I + X)^T[AY + Y^TA](I + X) = 0$ ?

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the $(I+X)^{-1}$ matrices; this was a convenient way to do so

Comment: But what properties allows you to say that $(I + X)^T[AY + Y^TA](I + X) = [AY + Y^TA]$? It seems like you are using the given $X^{T}AX=A$ but instead you are using $(I+X)$ somehow. You also can't just assume they are equivalent because $AY+Y^TA=0$, because that's what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @JungleFungus let $M = AY + Y^TA$, we're trying to show that $M=0$.  If we know that $(I+X)^TM(I+X) = 0$, then we can say that
$$
(I+X)^TM(I+X) = 0 \implies\\
[(I+X)^TM(I+X)](I + X)^{-1} = 0(I+X)^{-1} \implies\\
(I+X)^TM = 0 \implies\\
(I+X)^{-T}(I+X)M = (I + X)^{-T}0 \implies\\
M = 0
$$
The point was not that $(I + X)^TM(I + X) = M$.

Comment: I'm still not sure this makes sense... you are saying that if we know $(I+X)^TM(I+X) = 0$ then we can show that it does equal zero. Isn't that circular reasoning? The point is that we don't know that $M = 0$, so we have to assume that it could be anything, then prove that it indeed is zero.

Comment: @JungleFungus In my answer, I show that $(I + X)^TM(I + X) = 0$.  In my comment, I use the fact that $(I + X)^TM(I + X) = 0$ to show that $M = 0$, which is exactly the conclusion we wanted.