# "Self-congruent" matrices examples

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, congruence-relations

Let's consider just (square) matrices with real entries.
Any matrix is congruent to itself, i.e. $$A=B^TAB$$
for $B=I$.
But we have also the case of orthogonal matrices $O$, where (e.g.) $I=O^TIO$, or symplectic matrices $S$ where $J=S^TJS$ ($J$ is the standard symplectic matrix). Except these examples, are there other "notable" cases of this relation?

Comment: When $A$ is nonsingular, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3340355) of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the vectorized form of the problem:

$$
\text{vec}\, A = \text{vec}\,(B^TAB) = (B^T \otimes B^T) \text{vec}\, A
$$

Rearranging, we get the homogeneous linear equation:

$$
[I_{n^2} - (B^T \otimes B^T)] \text{vec} A = 0
$$

where $n$ is the number of rows and columns in $A$ and $B$. The only way this can have a solution other than $A = 0$ is if the matrix $[I_{n^2} - (B^T \otimes B^T)]$ has a zero eigenvalue. The eigenvalues of this matrix are

$$
\text{eig}\, [I_{n^2} - (B^T \otimes B^T)] = \{1 - \lambda\mu,\ \lambda,\mu \in \text{eig} B\}
$$

In other words, your equation has a solution other than $A = 0$ if and only if the product of any two (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues of $B$ equals one. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "notable" cases of the equation, but this is certainly a place to start looking for other interesting examples.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with some of the terminology, however I'll work on it and I thank you in between!

Comment: What terms are you unfamiliar with? I am guessing it is the vectorization operator $\text{vec} X$ and the Kronecker product, $X \otimes X$. A google and/or Wikipedia search should lead you to some sources with good background information; neither concept is terribly difficult.

Comment: @teerav42 Very, very nice answer. I liked reading it and learned something from it!

Comment: Your guess is correct :-). I'm looking at the Wiki pages right now!

Comment: @amsmath thank you! :)

Comment: Got it. Great answer @teerav42 ! I'll wait just 24h for the sake of discussion before accepting it

Comment: @teerav42 , understanding tensor products is a very good thing; yet, here $A$ is given and the unknown is $B$; then we considered the non-linear equation $A=X^TAX$ and not the linear equation $X=B^TXB$.

Comment: @loupblanc you're right. I am not sure if it is possible to solve explicitly for B in terms of A.

Answer (score 1):

Here $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. We considered the non-linear equation $A=X^TAX$ in the unknown $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

When $A$ is a generic matrix (for example, randomly choose it), it can be proved that the set of solutions $X$ is an algebraic set of dimension $\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor$ (that is, $X$ depends on $\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor$ algebraically independent parameters).

The examples you give ($O(n)$ and the symplectic matrices) are very special. They are groups composed by matrices that preserve a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand the difference - among the $X$ matrices depending on $n/2$ parameters aren't there other examples of matrices preserving a bilinear form?

Comment: Absolutely. Yet, if you choose a random matrix $A$, then the obtained set is not interesting. In general, we choose a symmetric or a skew-symmetric matrix $A$; then $A$ is structured and the  preserving algebraic set is much bigger; its dimension is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Enlightening!, thanks one more time